# VBA SaveCopy function + lose a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I created an Excel 2016-based template, which the user can fill and create a work form based on it. User inserts an unique ID and with basic `INDEX&MATCH` formulas some ID-related parameters are being fetched from separate worksheet `a`. The work form is created with VBA-macro using `SaveCopyAs` method.

After the parameters have been fetched and VBA is launched to create the work form the ID will not change anymore. Thus, I don't need the whole worksheet `a` anymore and would like to drop it to keep the work form more lightweight. I'm capable of retaining the fetched parameters, so this is not a problem.

I would NOT want the user to have to re-open the form every single time a work form is created, so I don't want the VBA to remove worksheet `a` from the template itself, as even though the user can't save changes to the template, (s)he would have to re-open the template file every time a work form has to be created.

Any idea if something could be done? Might it be possible to somehow run `SaveCopyAs` or similar method, but drop the worksheet `a` at the same time from the new target file? Having `INDEX&MATCH` formula fetch the needed information from another workbook would theoretically work but to my knowledge requires the other workbook to be open at all times which will undoubtedly start to cause unnecessary issues.

My current VBA for work form creating is something like this:

```
Sub Save_copy()

Dim FileName As String

With ActiveWorkbook 

[H3] = Format(Now, "dd.mm.yy_hhmm")
Range("H2").Value = Range("H1").Value

  FileName = "SERVICE " & _
        Range("H1").Value & _
        " - " & Format(Now, "dd.mm.yy") & _
        "_" & Format(Now, "hhmm") & _
        "." & Right(.Name, Len(.Name) - InStrRev(.Name, "."))

  .SaveCopyAs "G:\SERVICE" & "\" & FileName
End With

Call Reset

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you properly try something like this ("air-coded" so there may be typos):

```
Sub Save_copy()

  Dim FileName As String

  With ActiveWorkbook

    [H3] = Format(Now, "dd.mm.yy_hhmm")
    Range("H2").Value = Range("H1").Value

    FileName = "SERVICE " & _
               Range("H1").Value & _
               " - " & Format(Now, "dd.mm.yy") & _
               "_" & Format(Now, "hhmm") & _
               "." & Right(.Name, Len(.Name) - InStrRev(.Name, "."))

    .SaveCopyAs "G:\SERVICE\" & FileName
  End With

  Dim newWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
  Set newWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("G:\service\" & FileName)
  newWorkbook.Worksheets("A").Delete
  newWorkbook.Close True

  Reset

End Sub
```

Additionally, a couple of coding tips:

- There's no need for `Call` - that function is deprecated and only exists to keep ancient code from blowing up
- There is an extra concatenation of the `"\"` in your `.SaveCopyAs` line - simply put the trailing slash in with the rest of the path (as I did).
- The unqualified `Range("H2")` refers to the `ActiveWorksheet` and could blow up on you if your user ever happens to click on a different worksheet while your code is running